How to use mysql's CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from python?
I want to use the MySQLs function CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from python code, but can't figure out how to pass this in my INSERT or UPDATE queries.
    try:
    mycursor.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (pkID bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , tsTest TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (pkID));")
    sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO test (tsTest) VALUES (%s);"
    valsInsert = ['CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', ]
    mycursor.execute(sqlInsert, valsInsert)
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print("MySQL error: {}".format(err))

I've tried: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()' and even mysql.connector.Timestamp
MySQL just throws: Incorrect datetime value:
Yes, I know I can use python's Now() function, but this might be problematic if the code is run on a different server than the DB. So, I'd prefer to use the mySQL function for all timestamps.
TIA!

Query parameters are always treated as scalar values, not expressions or keywords. So it's executed as if you had run this query:
INSERT INTO test (tsTest) VALUES ('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')

This is like a string literal, not the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function. MySQL may attempt to cast the string value to whatever the column's data type is, but this is not going to work in the case of a timestamp or datetime.
If you want to insert an expression, just put the expression your query, not using a parameter.
sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO test (tsTest) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);"

